# display last object from dynamically updating array + emberjs + handlebars

Tags: ember.js, handlebars.js

I am using rails 4 with emberjs. I have an array of users that I get from the server. I need to display the last object on the UI. Also, the user can add new users to the array but only the last/latest-added user should be visible.

My ember version details are as

```
Ember      : 1.7.0-beta.1
Ember Data : 1.0.0-beta.8.2a68c63a
Handlebars : 1.3.0
jQuery     : 1.11.1
```

My current handlebars code is as. After adding the new user to users array, the new user details is displayed.

```
{{each users}}
  //display all the users here.
{{/each}}
```

What i want is something like this

```
{{#each users}}
  {{#if @last}} 
    //display user details
  {{/if}}
{{/each}}
```

I tried adding a property in the associated controller and removed the 'each' loop. I displayed the lastUser details which works. But if I add a new user, the UI still displays
the previous user details.

```
lastUser: (->                                                                                                                             
  return @model.users.get('lastObject')
).property('@model.users')
```

How can this be acheived? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You can simply use the following:

```
{{users.lastObject.firstName}}
{{users.lastObject.lastName}}
```

or more cleanly:

```
{{#with users.lastObject}}
  {{firstName}}
  {{lastName}}
{{/with}}
```

With just redefines `this` within the block to the object provided--in this case the `users.lastObject` object.  Your `lastUser` computed property is unnecessary because Ember enumerables already provide this for free!

Comment: Worth noting: you're probably going to want to make sure your `users` array is sorted by something meaningful--there's no guarantee that the store is going to have your records in an order that makes sense to you!

Answer (score 1):

To watch additions to the users array, you need to watch the `'users.@each'`

See the following documentation http://emberjs.com/guides/object-model/computed-properties-and-aggregate-data/